# Passing function and data from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

In my App.js file

```
import Fruits from "./Fruits";
import FruitsCounter from "./FruitsCounter";
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([
        {fruitName: 'apple', id: 1},
        {fruitName: 'apple', id: 2},
        {fruitName: 'plum', id: 3},
  ]);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setFruits = fruits.length - 1;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Where should the state go?</h1>
      <Fruits name={fruits} set={ handleClick}/>
      <FruitsCounter name={fruits} set={ handleClick}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In Fruits.js

```
import React from "react";

function Fruits(props) {
    

    return (
        <div>
            {props.name.map(f => <p key={f.id} onClick={props.set}>{f.fruitName}</p>)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Fruits
```

and in FruitsCounter.js component

```
function FruitsCounter(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Total fruits: {props.name.length}</h2>
    )
}

export default FruitsCounter;
```

by clicking a fruit name, I want to decrease the counter value by one. how can I pass setFruits from app to counter and use it.

Answer (score 0):

you define setFruits here as a function that can update the value of fruits & fruits as an object.

```
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([
        ...
  ]);
```

Then pass it to other components as this:

```
 <Fruits name={fruits} set={setFruits}/>
```

Also change the handle. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there, but should be something like this. But I don't think it is doing what you think is doing.

```
  const handleClick = () => {
  setFruits((fruits, props) => ({
  fruits: fruits.length-1;
}))  
}
```

with previous handle you were redefining setFruits to something different than a function. with this handle you're just using it.

a more simple example of using setFruits.

```
setFruits([...fruits, {fruitName: 'onion', id: 7} ])
```

check https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html and search for

> this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their
> values for calculating the next state

Comment: Actually I also want to change the counter value by clicking the fruit name. How to pass the changed value of the length to the fruitsCounter

Comment: then you pass     <FruitsCounter fruits={fruits} /> and use it like this
<h2>total fruits:{props.fruits.length}<h2/>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the fruit from the list on click.

```js
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([
        {fruitName: 'apple', id: 1},
        {fruitName: 'apple', id: 2},
        {fruitName: 'plum', id: 3},
  ]);
  const removeFruit = (id) => {
    setFruits(currentFruits => {
       return currentFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.id !== id)
    })
  }
 return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <Fruits name={fruits} removeFruit={ handleClick}/>
      ...
    </div>
  );
```

then in your Fruits component you can call register an onClick callback that calls `removeFruit` with the id of the fruit you want to remove.

```
<div>
      {props.name.map(fruit => (
        <p key={fruit.id} onClick={() => props.removeFruit(fruit.id)}>
          {fruit.fruitName}
        </p>
      ))}
</div>
```

BTW: I recommend that you rename the properties of your components to something that makes more sense like this:

```
- <Fruits name={fruits} set={ handleClick}/>
+ <Fruits fruits={fruits} onRemoveFruit={removeFruit}/>
```

Comment: Actually I also want to change the counter value by clicking the fruit name. How to pass the changed value of the length to the fruitsCounter . I lost here. Sure, I'll change the names of props as you recommend

Comment: so `fruit.id` should be `fruitCount` instead? `fruits.lenght` is a dynamic/calculated property there is no way to change it except for adding or removing entries from the `fruits` array.